# export products csv image path meaning

Tags: image, magmi

i'export a csv file by using export data workflow profile(export all products) by using magento admin, and i see the exported image path like /1/3/1330519_1.jpg.

```
/0/7/07aledtv_26.jpg
/0/7/07aledtv_26.jpg
/1/3/1330519_1.jpg
/1/3/1330511_1.jpg
/0/2/0210265_1.jpg
/2/9/2960019_1.jpg
/0/7/07aledtv_27.jpg

/0/7/07aledtv_28.jpg
/0/7/07aledtv_28.jpg
/0/7/07aledtv_28.jpg
/1/3/1330520_1.jpg
/0/7/07aledtv_28.jpg
/0/7/07aledtv_28.jpg
/2/5/2550075_3.jpg
/7/6/7630004_5.jpg
/0/2/0210317_1.jpg
/2/3/2310321_1.jpg
/0/7/07aledtv_28.jpg
/1/3/1330521_1.jpg
```

So, anyone know what is the /1/3/ is actually referring? categoryID?

And i use magmi try to import, how do i map the using Image attributes processor v1.0.25, what is the new csv format should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento stores images in separate folders inside `media/catalog/product`
So if you upload an image called `abcd.png` it will be stored in `a/b/abcd.png`.
it takes the first 2 letters of the image name and creates 2 folders.

If you upload an image called `a.jpg` it will be stored in `a/_/a.jpg`.

This makes the image searching a little faster.
If all the images were in the same folder then you can end up with hundreds of thousands of images and the directory scanning would be slower.

Sorry but I could answer only one of your questions. I've never used magmi and I don't know how it works.

Comment: nice explanation +1

Answer (score 0):

The export location of the images is where the images live once they are actually installed into the magento website. The import path is different. If you are importing via magento's import the images need to be in /media/import ( see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486990/magento-importing-images )

Using Magmi, you can pretty much define any path you want to the import images (Magmi is MUCH better than default magento at this), but there are a few rules in notation in the magmi csv format. Basically you can define the path to the thumbnail, small and large images, you can add a + or - at the front of the path to say if the image should be included in the media library for the product (ie will it be included in the product page as an alternate view) and finally you can add lists of images to the media library by listing image import paths separated by semicolons.

There is fine documentation on this in the magmi online help here ( http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Main_Page )